# Compiler executable file C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.0

I had an application on .Net Framework 4.0 and MVC2 running on Visual Studio 2010. I decided to move this application to Visual Studio 2015. So First I've upgraded it to MVC3 and then Opened it with Visual Studio 2015 and because the System.Web.MVC and some other dlls were missing. I installed Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc v3.0.50813.1 from Nuget. Now my application are being compiled successfully. But after running it, it displays this error:

```
Compiler executable file C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe cannot be found.
```

The file csc.exe exists in my Framework64 directory, but not in Framework directory.

PS: I has some difficulty installing Visual Studio 2015 and I would prefer a solution doesn't need reinstalling Visual Studio.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Compiler executable file C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe cannot be found.]
   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.Compile(CompilerParameters options, String compilerDirectory, String compilerExe, String arguments, String& outputFile, Int32& nativeReturnValue, String trueArgs) +6840643
   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +473
   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +186
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +24
   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() +950
   System.Web.Compilation.<>c.<PerformBuild>b__22_0(AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder) +13
   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass42_0`2.<PartitionerForEachWorker>b__1() +1321
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() +43
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask) +18
   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object ) +208
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +132
   System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed) +502
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories) +125
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileResourcesDirectory() +32
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +227

[HttpException (0x80004005): Compiler executable file C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe cannot be found.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +62
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +435
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +33
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +545

[HttpException (0x80004005): Compiler executable file C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe cannot be found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9947444
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Comment: which windows do you use? try to repair .net 4.x

Answer (score -1):

Mvc3 is not supported after visual studio 2010
You will have to update to a newer version of mvc